# need to define a foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

Tags: go, go-gorm

how to solve this? I got an error like this

invalid field found for struct gomar/campaign.Campaign's field User, need to define a foreign key for relations or it need to implement the Valuer/Scanner interface

```
package campaign

import (
    "gomar/user"
    "time"
)

type Campaign struct {
    ID               int
    userID           int
    Name             string
    ShortDescription string
    Description      string
    Slug             string
    CreatedAt        time.Time
    UpdatedAt        time.Time
    CampaignImages   []CampaignImage
    User             user.User
}

type CampaignImage struct {
    ID         int
    CampaignID int
    FileName   string
    IsPrimary  int
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    UpdatedAt  time.Time
}
```

Answer (score 0):

need to added a tag to user.User as per the [official doc](https://gorm.io/docs/has_many.html)!.

```golang
type Campaign struct {
    ID               int
    userID           int
    Name             string
    ShortDescription string
    Description      string
    Slug             string
    CreatedAt        time.Time
    UpdatedAt        time.Time
    CampaignImages   []CampaignImage
    User             user.User  `gorm:"foreignKey:Uid"`
}

type CampaignImage struct {
    ID         int
    CampaignID int
    FileName   string
    IsPrimary  int
    CreatedAt  time.Time
    UpdatedAt  time.Time
}
```

Please also perform migration for user.User

```
err := DB.AutoMigrate(&user.User{})
if err != nil {
  panic("migration failed")
}
```